# How to evaluate a reciprocal function

Tags: jquery, calculated-field

I am building a basic jQuery calculator. Everything was going good, until I tried doing the reciprocal function. I have it bound to a click event. The code looks like this

```
// inverse is $(".row li.inverse")
inverse.on("click", function () {
    // textBox is $("input#result")
    var val = textBox.val(),
        text = parseFloat(val),
        recip = eval(1/text);
    textBox.val(recip);
});
```

So on the click of the button with the class `inverse`, it should get the value of what is in the `input`, and turn it into a number. It should then `eval` the number as 1 divided by the number, and set the textbox value equal to the answer. But when I click the button, the value stays the same. However, when I put the code into firebug without the click handler, it works just fine. Where am I going wrong?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpCvN/)

Comment: You are registering the handler multiple times. So reciprocal of reciprocal of etc even number of times gives the same result.

Comment: @PSL How am I registering it multiple times?

Comment: `key.each(function () {` i.e You have 22 keys and in the .each loop you are binding the handlers again and again... So it executes 22 times so inverse of inverse of 22 times gives the same result.

Comment: @PSL I removed it from the `key.each()` but I'm not really sure why it works now. Can you explain in answer form?

Comment: @CodyGuldner Sure shall explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 22 keys and in the `key.each` loop you are binding the handlers again and again So it 
executes 22 times. Which means each of your keys have the same event registered 22 times. So consider the reciprocal situation that you have. You are taking the value from the textbox and converting it into its reciprocal so that is one time, and you are good. But it happens 22 times so even number of reciprocal operations on the same value returns the same value itself. Also you do not need to use `eval`. Just do the proper operation. Also do remember that javascript performs [floating point arithmetic operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

```
  key.each(function () {


        if (!$(this).is(functions)) {
            $(this).on("click", function () {
                var number = $(this).text();
                // Inserts value of clicked button into the input
                textBox.val(textBox.val() + number);
            });
        }
    }); //<-- end it here

    var clear = $(".row li.clear"),
        backspace = $(".row li.back"),
        equals = $(".row li.equals"),
        inverse = $(".row li.inverse");
    clear.on("click", function () {
        // Clears the input value if the clear button is clicked
        textBox.val('');
    });
    backspace.on("click", function () {
        // Removes last character of input
    });
    equals.on("click", function () {
        $("#function").text(textBox.val());
        // Evaluates what is in the input
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Sets that to the value
            textBox.val(eval(textBox.val()));
        }, 1);
    });

    inverse.on("click", function () {
        var val = textBox.val(),
            text = parseFloat(val),
            recip = eval(1 / text);
        textBox.val(recip);
    });
```

Comment: Do I need to use `eval` with my other operations?

Comment: @CodyGuldner No just ignore them. According to me you don't need eval. Also need to be careful while using it.

Comment: So how do I evaluate the value of the textbox when it is a function such as `1+1`? I don't know how to evaluate the user input without using `eval()`

Comment: Yes, you use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) for string representation. But ideally a calculator kind of things if you support entering the operators and operands at once you should think about implementing it using expression parser.. I am not getting the correct terminology though